# How do I disable my talking login screen?

Tags: sound, login, accessibility

Managed to clip a shortkey that enabled some Audio assistance program on my Ubuntu login screen (it reads back to you anything you click or type).

It's really annoying, but I can't seem to find any documentation that will help me disable it

**Does anyone know how I might disable this?**

Answer (score 4):

The key combination you accidentally used was probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. It is a toggle switch, so if you use it again, Orca will quit and not bother you at next logon.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you turned-on the Screen reader . You can disable it in system settings as

[image]